# Why is ORDER BY not working in a Presto query?

Tags: t-sql, presto, trino, treasure-data

I have a fairly simple Presto query, that is not ORDERing by the column I specified:

```
(SELECT 
  tag_monitor_domains.property_name,
  count(*) as HourCount
FROM pageviews
  INNER JOIN tag_monitor_domains 
  ON pageviews.property_id = CAST(tag_monitor_domains.property_id AS varchar) 
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(pageviews.time) > date_add('month', -1, CURRENT_DATE)
AND FROM_UNIXTIME(pageviews.time) < date_add('hour', -0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 DESC)
```

but the results are NOT ordered by property_name, the rows are random.

Comment: That is hard to believe.  Either the `order by` is not part of the query being run or you are misinterpreting the results.

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're getting for it?

Comment: Actually, I had neglected to include the parens wrapping the query (added now). I was troubleshooting a subselect and when running the query wrapped in parens, the ORDER BY fails. Without parens works fine. Thanks for your help troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @DShultz for the report. This is indeed the case and I reported https://github.com/trinodb/trino/issues/6008 for this. Let's continue there discussion whether this is desired or faulty behavior.

As a workaround.... well, remove parenthesis. But this you already know.

The more general reason for *why* this is the case -- Presto ignores ORDER BY where it doesn't change the semantics of the query (e.g. in subqueries), as governed by the SQL spec. See https://trino.io/blog/2019/06/03/redundant-order-by.html for more information.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL specification defines the following syntactic rules:

```
<query expression> ::=
  [ <with clause> ]
  <query expression body>
  [ <order by clause> ]
  [ <result offset clause> ]
  [ <fetch first clause> ]

<query expression body> ::=
    <query term>
  | <query expression body> UNION [ ALL | DISTINCT ] [ <corresponding spec> ] <query term>
  | <query expression body> EXCEPT [ ALL | DISTINCT ] [ <corresponding spec> ] <query term>

<query term> ::=
    <query primary>
  | <query term> INTERSECT [ ALL | DISTINCT ] [ <corresponding spec> ] <query primary>

<query primary> ::=
    <simple table>
  | <left paren>
       <query expression body>
       [ <order by clause> ]
       [ <result offset clause> ]
       [ <fetch first clause> ]
    <right paren>
```

A parenthesized query is a `<query expression>` that contains only a `<query primary>` of the shape `<left paren> <query expression body> ... <right paren>`

Further, the it specifies that:

> a) If `QE` does not immediately contain an `<order by clause>`, then the ordering of rows in `T` is implementation-dependent.

(QE is the `<query expression>`)

So, since the `<query expression>` doesn't immediately contain an ORDER BY clause in the case of a parenthesized `<query primary>`, the ordering is not guaranteed.

Presto optimizes out this case and produces a warning to indicate you might not get the results you expect:

```
presto> (SELECT x FROM (VALUES 1) t(x) ORDER BY x);
 x
---
 1
(1 row)

WARNING: ORDER BY in subquery may have no effect
```

To obtain the desired ordering, you need to make sure the `ORDER BY` clause is at the top-level, either by removing the parentheses as suggested in the other reply, or by moving it outside the parentheses:

```
(SELECT ...)
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Comment: I verified that even with the parentheses around (select ..), order by still does not work.